# How to divide up work when using QThreadPool/QRunnable?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use QT 5.12's QThreadPool to do some work that I previously did with std::thread, because the .joins are hanging the main thread and thus breaking the rendering of the GUI.

However, looking over the docs, I cannot figure out how to do so.

Here's an example of how I currently do this with std::thread: (semi-pseudocode)

```
  unsigned numThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

  if (numThreads == 1)
    {
      runThread(0, 1);
    }
  else
    {
      std::vector<std::thread> threads(numThreads);

      // Start the threads
      for (unsigned i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
        {
          threads[i] = std::thread(&myClass::runThread, this, i,
                                   numThreads);
        }

      // Wait for all threads to finish
      for (unsigned i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
        {
          threads[i].join();
        }
    }
```

Where runThread() looks like:

```
void runThread(const int threadID, const int numThreads)
{
  for (unsigned long i = threadID; i < tasks.size(); i += numThreads)
    {
      // Do the ith task here
    }
}
```

This is not perfect, but ensures all tasks get done, and no work is duplicated.

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do something equivalent in `QThreadPool`.

I can create a new class that uses the `QRunnable` interface, and implement a `run()` function.

However, there is no way to get the ID of the current thread. QThread offers two functions:

`QThread *QThread::currentThread()` and `Qt::HANDLE QThread::currentThreadId()`.

`currentThreadID` sounds promising, but it's actually a platform-specified identifier, not a numerical thread number. The docs warn against using it: "Warning: The handle returned by this function is used for internal purposes and **should not be used in any application code**."

Without a thread ID, how am I supposed to ensure that every task out of N tasks gets done, with no threads stepping on top of each other?

For example, a vector might contain 10 results, and I want each index of that vector to have one thread compute its answer. How do I do that with QThreadPool?

Comment: Very large ideology difference between the *use a ton of threads* approach and the *use a thread pool* approach. I recommend playing around with the thread pool in a simpler, lower-stakes problem to get a handle on how you should  use thread pools, then returning to your current problem and applying what you learned.

Comment: I was under the impression a thread pool was just a group of threads kept around to minimize the losses from creating and destroying threads. Is this not the case?

If a thread pool is not the right solution, how can I perform this longer-running task without hanging the GUI rendering?

Comment: writing threaded GUI code is a lot different than writing console applications, you can't use any blocking function in your main thread (such as join), instead you should have another thread that is submitting work and joining workers when the work is done **then** `Qsignal` the main thread that the work is done to start updating the GUI and join the *already finished* thread that just made that signal.

Comment: Thread pool is probably the right tool. You pass the thread pool a job, the thread pool schedules the job and sooner or later runs it. If you want firm guarantees on when the jobs finish, `waitForDone` in this case, you're back at the the `join`, but with the advantage of a timeout on the you can use to allow the UI to perform other tasks. Better if you don't though. And I see another coment has come in covering prtty much where I was going.

Comment: I think your first statement more indicates a lack of design then an inherent problem with std::thread. And you might have the same issue with a threadpool (which in itself is probably a good thing to use). Find a way to queue functions back on the mainthread (send messages to the mainthread something has happened and a result is ready)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments on my question, I reconsidered what I was doing and tried to create a more gui-minded solution. I got it working great, by doing the following:

1. Remove the join(). Once those threads are created, immediately exit that function and give control back to the main event loop, so nothing hangs.
2. Add a std::atomic for keeping track of the number of tasks completed, which each thread increments as it completes tasks.
3. Create a new signal, updateCompletion() that passes on the number of tasks completed to the main window. It uses that to update the QProgressDialog so a user can see progress as tasks complete. If all are finished, it closes the dialog.
4. Create a new signal, onThreadCompleted(), that is emitted when a thread exits that for loop.
5. Create a new slot for said signal, which joins the thread. Since the thread is already done, this happens essentially immediately.

By using signals and slots, I was able to keep everything the GUI running smoothly. I'll try to keep this more in mind for future work.